# Vba Code to Delete data based on a drop box choice

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that has a List box when that is selected codes appear.  If a code is selected, excel copies the data from a worksheet (with the same code) into a quotation sheet.

If I make a change and select another code in the same list box, I need excel to go and find the old data and delete it in the Quotation sheet.

```
Public Sub delete_selected_rows()
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngToDel As Range, c As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Q")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = .Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
    End With

    Set rng2 = Worksheets("SO").Range("D35")
    For Each c In rng1
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(c.Value, rng2, 0)) Then
            'if value from rng1 is found in rng2 then remember this cell for deleting
            If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToDel = c
            Else
                Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then rngToDel.CurrentRegion.Delete
End Sub
```

How can I get CurrentRegion to count an extra 30 rows the delete?

Answer (score 1):

VBA's ISERROR won't catch the error caused by a failed MATCH worksheet function. You need to construct that part differently.

```
Public Sub delete_selected_rows()

    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rngToDel As Range, c As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim R As Long

    With Worksheets("Q")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng1 = .Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
    End With

    Set rng2 = Worksheets("SO").Range("D35")
    For Each c In rng1
        On Error Resume Next
        R = 0
        R = WorksheetFunction.Match(c.Value, rng2, 0)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If R Then
            'if value from rng1 is found in rng2 then remember this cell for deleting
            ' R is the row number in rng2 where a match was found
            ' since rng2 is a single cell, R would always be 1, if found
            ' If rng2 = D35 MATCH be an overkill. Why not simply compare?
        Else
            If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToDel = c
            Else
                Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c

    If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then rngToDel.CurrentRegion.Delete
End Sub
```

Please observe my comments about rng2. Could there be some mistake? What does SO.D35 contain? If it contains a string of values one of which might be the one you look for MATCH is the wrong function to use.

It seems that you intend to put all items to be deleted on a spike and delete them in one go at the end. I'm not sure that is possible, and it's getting late for me. The more common approach would be to delete one row at a time, as you find them, because once you delete a row all row numbers below that row will change. You can run the entire code with ScreenUpdating turned off and set `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` after all the deleting has been done.

Comment: Thank you   SO is a sheet name for Sales order and D35 is a list box, where a code is selected, I have code that looksup the sheet with the same code and pastes it in the Q sheet.  On SO I have D35 - D43 all list boxes that copy content to the Q sheet.  If say D35 is changed for some reason I need that content that was copied to Q to be deleted (About 35 rows) These are copied one after another in the Q sheet.  Is there any way I can send you the spreadsheet.

Comment: If you would send me the spreadsheet then I would be doing the work and you would help me. Thank you, but I prefer it the other way around. Please stay in charge. If necessary, start a new question and put me in the "notify".

Comment: I understand D35 to be a cell on Worksheet("SO"). Therefore it couldn't be a list box. If it is a list box you can address it by its ID in the `Worksheets("SO").Shapes` collection. If you have several list boxes on that sheet you would do well to name them explicitly and meaningfully, and then refer to them like `Worksheets("SO").Shapes("Item List")`.  This alone would put most of my above code in the garbage. But once you have control of your list boxes you can look at their relationship and interaction with Sheet("Q").